# How to secure file, that can be downloaded only by some users in Codeigniter or raw PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wrote web application that has few access levels / groups (not logged in, worker, manager, admin).

For access control i used something similar to best answer here:

[What is the best practice for restricting specific pages to logged in users only in Codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819275/what-is-the-best-practice-for-restricting-specific-pages-to-logged-in-users-only)

Now i have to create download page that allows download only for groups which are allowed for specyfic file. Now i have links displayed only for allowed users, but I think I have to hide real file location somehow, because file URL is remembered by browsers and anyone can download file without any problems after logout.

Comment: just a question. what is the difference between codeigniter and raw php? codeigniter is just a framework. whatever works for raw php, will work for CI too.

Comment: probably a round about way of asking if there is already a CI method for this

Comment: @itachi - as Kai Qing wrote - i hoped that CI have some method or helper for this

Comment: yes, CI does have a helper. read the question I linked to to get the general idea. The CI helper should be easy to understand then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't link to the real file. You link to a script that uses an access token to validate, then passes the file. See this question:

[PHP Pass File Handle to user so that file downloads & saves to their machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539548/php-pass-file-handle-to-user-so-that-file-downloads-saves-to-their-machine)

Once downloaded you can either expire the token or just log how many times the user has downloaded and apply proper restrictions there.

Also, nest your files beneath web root or make sure you can't directly access them wherever you choose to store them

And YES, CI does have a helper for download:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I saw download helper in CI, but i was not sure what is this for and what im searching for.

Comment: Where i should put function for download? Shall i create controller for download?

Comment: It's a helper, so you would just call it from the method in your controller responsible for handling downloads. Say for example, yoursite.com/downloads/file_id/access_token - assuming downloads is a class who has only an index method and file_id and access_token are parameters passed to index. In there you would load the download helper after the token has been verified

Comment: by the way, you may need to define that setup in routes $route['downloads/:any'] = "downloads"; then have the index method search for URI parameters: $file_id = $this->uri->segment(2);

Comment: Thanks again Kai Qing. Very useful tip with route. Im CI newbie and i didn't knew that i can use something like `:any` in routing. It looks like i have to read more CI documentation, maybe i will find something else useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a sessionID to the download script.  The download script could compare that sessionID against current sessionID's to make sure it is valid. And if valid allow for a download.

Comment: This is not what i need. I need to create that download script and i didn't knew how. Anyway - thanks.