# What is the link to download google suggest javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to link google suggestions to my website. I think there might be something wrong with the link i am using or with way i am trying to read the file. Anyways this is the link and the code i am using in my php file

```
$filehandle=fopen("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=" . $_GET["qu"],"r")
```

in my php file.
Still it doesnt seem to work.

When I `window.alert(httpobject.responseText)` in my AJAX file it shows blank. What could be the possible problem?
This is my php code:

```
<?php
    $filehandle=fopen("http://suggestqueries.google.com/completesearch?client=firefox&q=" . $_GET["qu"],"r");
    while(!feof($filehandle))
    {
        $download=fgets($filehandle);
        echo $download;
    }
    fclose($filehandle);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$filetype = mime_content_type($filename);
header('Content-type: '.$filetype);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a previous question that may help point you in a better direction. [PHP Pass File Handle to user so that file downloads & saves to their machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539548)

You may also consider updating your post with more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `file_get_contents` instead of opening the file, reading it line by line and then outputting each line and then closing the file. I don't see why your code wouldn't work though.

I don't know anything about the "Google Suggest" but i think this should work.

```
echo file_get_contents("http://suggestqueries.google.com/completesearch?client=firefox&q=" . $_GET["qu"]);
```